# How do I pull a specfic part of string pattern from one column and insert it into another column in the same table in Microsoft Access?

Tags: ms-access-2010

I have one specific table that is gonna be used as possible relation between two tables in my database. This Table Right now has some specific values gotten from a insert query, these value's are called BIB ID's. This is written as BIB (ID: 1), BIB (ID: 10), BIB (ID:1000), etc.

Now I tried solving this by using a column ID, that is auto numbering however the problem is that some value's like 11 are missing, which is intentional.

[Image to Illustrate](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CPUiA.png)

```
ARTICLE_PATH--> ID

BIB (ID: 1) 1   
BIB (ID: 2) 2   
BIB (ID: 3) 3   
BIB (ID: 4) 4   
BIB (ID: 5) 5   
BIB (ID: 6) 6   
BIB (ID: 7) 7   
BIB (ID: 8) 8   
BIB (ID: 9) 9   
BIB (ID: 10) 10

BIB (ID: 12) 11
```

So what basically needs to happen is that the string in position X needs to be copied so: BIB (ID: posX). The thing is how do I do this?

Before you give me an answer I know that at first glance the Function Right$ seems to be a solution to my problem but from my understanding these functions need a specific length part.

However this is not a option since the length of the string is variable.

What I am looking for is a pattern function or something similar. If it can be solved using the right function please explain it to me clearly. Thank you in advance. Also I do not know if I need to use SQL instead, if I do let me know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the solution to my problem with a search and replace query which I should add now here:

```
SELECT 
    ARTICLES.ARTICLE_NAME, ARTICLES.ARTICLE_PATH, ARTICLES.ARTICLE_LINK,     
    REPLACE([ARTICLE_PATH], "BIB (ID: ", "") AS ID, 
    REPLCAE([ID],")","") AS AANWINSTNR
FROM 
    ARTICLES
WHERE 
    (((ARTICLES.ARTICLE_PATH) LIKE "BIB (*"));
```

Also the following copy query:

```
INSERT INTO BIB_ID (ARTICLE_PATH, AANWINSTNR)
    SELECT 
        QRY_SELECTION_BIB_ARTICLES.ARTICLE_PATH,  
        QRY_SELECTION_BIB_ARTICLES.AANWINSTNR
    FROM 
        QRY_SELECTION_BIB_ARTICLES;
```